# error while loading shared libraries: libpoppler.so.58: cannot open shared object file

Tags: linux, ubuntu, path, shared-libraries, poppler

I compiled and install poppler-0.39.0 as per the instruction. By default header files went int `\usr\local\include` and lib files went into `\usr\local\lib`. pdftohtml is installed in `\usr\local\bin`.

Now when I tried to run `pdftohtml` it gives following error.

```
pdftohtml: error while loading shared libraries: libpoppler.so.58: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory.
```

Though `libpoppler.so.58` is present in `\usr\local\lib`. Please help me.

Comment: This issue is resolved now.

Comment: Would you please share your solution? I am having this problem right now.

Answer (score 12):

I had a similar problem on Ubuntu 18.04. After installation I got this error:

```
error while loading shared libraries: libpoppler.so.90: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

It turned out it was installed to `/usr/local/lib`:

```
Install the project...
-- Install configuration: "RelWithDebInfo"
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib/libpoppler.so.90.0.0
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib/libpoppler.so.90
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib/libpoppler.so
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/poppler.pc
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/poppler-splash.pc
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/poppler-qt5.pc
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/poppler-glib.pc
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/poppler-cairo.pc
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/poppler-cpp.pc
```

but the system wasn't looking there.

To check if `/usr/local/lib` is in the default directories to search you can take a look at `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/libc.conf`.

If not already there you can add: `/usr/local/lib`

In my case this was already the case:

```
# libc default configuration
/usr/local/lib
```

But the cache at `/etc/ld.so.cache` wasn't updated.

To do so run *(as `root` / `sudo`)*:

```
ldconfig
```

Solved the problem for me. Hope this may be helpful for someone!

Comment: I had a similar problem with pdfgrep and libpopler.so.0. I wasn't able to check if the library of libpopler.so.0 was in the default directories but just running as sudo ldconfig was enough for me

Comment: That feeling when you find the fix to your problem only to realize you have been here before and already upvoted the question and correct answer.  Thank you sir, I am sorry I have but only 1 upvote to give.

Answer (score 1):

Just had this very same error message displayed in an Amazon Linux 64 bits box. I guess pdftotext was looking for libpoppler.so.58 inside /usr/lib64/ but the lib was located on /usr/lib

So i ran the following commands (as superuser):

#### $ cp /usr/lib/libpoppler.so.58.0.0 /usr/lib64

#### $ ldconfig

You may have to replace directories to make that fit your case.
I'm not sure if it's the most correct workaround but it worked.